# JQuery onclick slideDown element and change id only working once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to show a new element everytime a button is clicked, this is what i came up with:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('#addNew').click(function() {
        $('#D2').slideDown();
        this.id = '#addNew2';   
    });

    $('#addNew2').click(function() {
        $('#D3').slideDown();
        this.id = '#addNew3';   
    });

    $('#addNew3').click(function() {
        $('#D4').slideDown();
        this.id = '#addNew4';   
    });

});
```

also here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QZF4S/

It Works fine the first time but and the id changes but it doesn't work after that?

Before this i tried using a if else statement to check if the element was display block and if it was open the next element on click. but this had the same problem, would only work once

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {

var arr=new Array('D1','D2','D3','D4');
var clickCount=0;

    jQuery('#addNew').click(function() {
            clickCount++;       
        $("#"+arr[clickCount]).slideDown();

   });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue lies with where you're tying in your function.  The document doesn't include the secondary ids when it is loaded so the `#addNew2` click function is never attached to the link because the link's ID is changed in the first click event.

You can nest the events if you know it will be a set number of items.  Here's the updated fiddle with this case: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6yHu/

If you want this to be interminable and add as many items as the user wants you'll need to create a stand alone function that performs the operations and then attach this function to your `addNew` click event but leave the ID the same.  Inside the secondary function you can detect the number of added elements and perform your operations based on what is present.

Answer (score 0):

**Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .click()**

In your code , you are changing an ID of element, `click` event handler doesnt know about dynamically created elements.

To handle this you can use

```
$(document).on( eventName, selector, function () {
} ); // attaches event handler current set of matched element as well as dynamically created elements.
```

### [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/QZF4S/24/)

### Reference [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)